# please help me with self-reference pointer

Tags: java, pointers, parameters, parameter-passing, bluej

i have written two classes first one Member and second one Store. and i wrote a method which can create an object from the member class and i am trying to to write a field store of type Store in the Member class and i want it store a reference to the store the member has entered. 
some told me to do this :
memberRegister() needs to be passed, as an argument, a pointer to the Store object that you are currently in.

In fact, the Store object needs to be able to tell the Member object "point to me". That is, the Store object needs a pointer to itself.
 but i did not get it

this is Member class

```
private int pinNumber;
private String name, id; 
private Store store;


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Member
 */
public Member(String name, String id, int pinNumber, Store store)

{
    // initialise instance variables
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.pinNumber = pinNumber;
    checkId();
    checkPinNumber();
}

/**
 * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
 * 
 * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
 * @return     the sum of x and y 
 */
private void checkId()
{
    // put your code here
    int length; 
     length = id.length();
    if (length > 10 ){
        System.out.println("lentgh must be at 10 ");
    }
}
private void checkPinNumber()
{
    int length; 
     length = id.length();
    if ((length > 4) && (length < 4 )){
        System.out.println("lentgh must be at 4"); 
}
```

class store

```
   private String storeName;
private int total; 
private  Member member;


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Store
 */
public Store(String storeName, int total)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    this.storeName = storeName;
    this.total = total;
}

/**
 * 
 */
public String getStoreName() 
{
return storeName;
}

/**
 * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
 * 
 * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
 * @return     the sum of x and y 
 */
public Member memberRegister(String name, String id, int pinNumber)
{
    // put your code here
   Member member;
   member = new Member(name, id, pinNumber)
   return member;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `this` suffice? I.e. `return new Member(name, id, pinNumber, this);`?

Comment: @Kerrek this would do if the constructor would store the store in it's private member variable, which it doesn't do.

Answer (score 1):

your memberRegister method doesn't invoke your Member constructor correctly:

```
public Member memberRegister(String name, String id, int pinNumber)
{
    // put your code here
   Member member;
   member = new Member(name, id, pinNumber, this) //this passes in a reference to your store
   return member;
}
```

Then you assign the reference in your Member constructor:

```
public Member(String name, String id, int pinNumber, Store store)

{
    // initialise instance variables
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.store = store //where this.store is a Store
    this.pinNumber = pinNumber;
    checkId();
    checkPinNumber();
}
```

Hope that helps. By the way, update the comments in a way, that they match your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using the keyword `this` is how you are able to get a self-referential pointer. You should be able to do as @Kerrek SB suggested and `return new Member(name, id, pinNumber, this)` from inside the `memberRegister` method.

Answer (score 0):

See in your case passing `this` keyword to method `memberRegister` is `useless`

`returning` `this` keyword is `useful`.

to know more about this keyword [check this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)